# How to use comparison operators on previous user input in CLIPS?

Tags: clips

I'm a beginner to CLIPS. The goal of this program is to return the name of the company that best matches the user's demographics. I ask the user their gender and (might be storing it wrong) store it into input, ethnicity stored into input2, and age into input3. I'm running into errors when trying to do comparisons to return the company name. Eg. if input=1 (man), then compare the demographics of men in both companies and return the name of the company with more men.

(= 1 input) this line in the last rule gives me error "Function '=' expected argument #2 to be of type integer or float." which I thought I've already only allowed responses of integers. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```
(deftemplate company
   (slot name)
   (slot men)
   (slot women)
   (slot Asian)
   (slot Black)
   (slot Latinx)
   (slot Indigenous)
   (slot White)
   (slot Other)
   (slot <18)
   (slot 18-20)
   (slot 21-29)
   (slot 30-39)
   (slot 40+))

(deffacts demographics
   (company (name Google)(men 0.669)(women 0.331)(Asian 0.428)(Black 0.088)(Latinx 0.088)(Indigenous 0.007)(White 0.445)(Other 0)(<18 0.02)(18-20 0.11)(21-29 0.59)(30-39 0.19)(40+ 0.07))
   (company (name Apple)(men 0.652)(women 0.348)(Asian 0.279)(Black 0.094)(Latinx 0.148)(Indigenous 0.007)(White 0.438)(Other 0.032)(<18 0.01)(18-20 0.1)(21-29 0.57)(30-39 0.22)(40+ 0.06)))

(defrule begin => (assert (phase select-gender)))

(defrule menu (phase select-gender) => 
   (printout t "Do you identify as a (1) man or (2) woman?: ") (assert (userinput (read))))

(defrule selection-okay
  ?phase <- (phase select-gender)
   ?input <- (userinput ?select&1|2)
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (assert (selection ?select))
   (assert (phase select-ethnicity)))

(defrule selection-nokay
   ?phase <- (phase select-gender)
   ?input <- (userinput ?select&~1&~2)
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (assert (phase select-gender))
   (printout t ?select " is not a valid response. Please enter 1 or 2."crlf))

(defrule menu2 (phase select-ethnicity) =>
   (printout t "Do you identify as (1)Asian, (2)Black, (3)Latinx, (4)Indigenous, (5)White, or (6)Other?: ") (assert (userinput2 (read))))

(defrule selection-okay2
   ?phase <- (phase select-ethnicity)
   ?input2 <- (userinput2 ?select&1|2|3|4|5|6)
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (assert (selection ?select))
   (assert (phase select-age)))

(defrule selection-nokay2
   ?phase <- (phase select-ethnicity)
   ?input2 <- (userinput2 ?select&~1&~2&~3&~4&~5&~6)
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (assert (phase select-ethnicity))
   (printout t ?select " is not a valid response. Please enter 1 through 6."crlf))

(defrule menu3 (phase select-age) =>
   (printout t "You are age: (1)<18, (2)18-20, (3)20-30, (4)30-40, (5)40+?: ") (assert (userinput3 (read))))

(defrule selection-okay3
   ?phase <- (phase select-age)
   ?input3 <- (userinput3 ?select&1|2|3|4|5)
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (assert (selection ?select))
   (assert (phase company-gender-men)))

(defrule selection-nokay3
   ?phase <- (phase select-age)
   ?input3 <- (userinput3 ?select&~1&~2&~3&~4&~5)
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (assert (phase select-age))
   (printout t ?select " is not a valid response. Please enter 1 through 5."crlf))

(defrule get-company-by-gender-men
   ?phase <- (company-gender-men)
   (= 1 input)
   (> (fact-slot-value 1 men) (fact-slot-value 2 men))
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (printout t (fact-slot-value 1 name) crlf))

;(fact-slot-value 1 name)
;(> (fact-slot-value 1 men) (fact-slot-value 2 men))
```

I have tried removing some extra code just to see if I can access the previous user input but I'm still not getting an output.

```
(deftemplate company
   (slot name)
   (slot men)
   (slot women)
   (slot Asian)
   (slot Black)
   (slot Latinx)
   (slot Indigenous)
   (slot White)
   (slot Other)
   (slot <18)
   (slot 18-20)
   (slot 21-29)
   (slot 30-39)
   (slot 40+))

(deffacts demographics
   (company (name Google)(men 0.669)(women 0.331)(Asian 0.428)(Black 0.088)(Latinx 0.088)(Indigenous 0.007)(White 0.445)(Other 0)(<18 0.02)(18-20 0.11)(21-29 0.59)(30-39 0.19)(40+ 0.07))
   (company (name Apple)(men 0.652)(women 0.348)(Asian 0.279)(Black 0.094)(Latinx 0.148)(Indigenous 0.007)(White 0.438)(Other 0.032)(<18 0.01)(18-20 0.1)(21-29 0.57)(30-39 0.22)(40+ 0.06)))

(defrule begin => (assert (phase select-gender)))

(defrule menu (phase select-gender) => 
   (printout t "Do you identify as a (1) man or (2) woman?: ") (assert (userinput (read)))(assert(phase select-ethnicity)))

(defrule menu2 (phase select-ethnicity) =>
   (printout t "Do you identify as (1)Asian, (2)Black, (3)Latinx, (4)Indigenous, (5)White, or (6)Other?: ") (assert (userinput2 (read)))(assert(phase select-age)))

(defrule menu3 (phase select-age) =>
   (printout t "You are age: (1)<18, (2)18-20, (3)20-30, (4)30-40, (5)40+?: ") (assert (userinput3 (read)))(assert(phase company-gender-men)))

(defrule get-company-by-gender-men
   ?phase <- (company-gender-men)
   (userinput ?userinput)
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (printout t ?userinput "can see user input"crlf))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defrule get-company-by-gender-men
   ?phase <- (phase company-gender-men)
   (userinput 1)
   (company (name ?name) (men ?men1))
   (company (men ?men2))
   (test (> ?men1 ?men2))
   =>
   (retract ?phase)
   (printout t ?name crlf))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response Gary. I've tried your solution and while I don't get any errors, I also don't get a printout even inputting all 1's. I see that you're grabbing the ?name, ?men1 and ?men2 from the facts in order to do the comparison and output the company name.  I have even removed the (userinput 1) line and just tested it with the comparison only, with no output as well.

Comment: I've noticed I had some errors with my phases and as such it wasn't outputting correctly. Gary's answer was very perfect and succinct way to do my tests.